# Validación del XSD Schema

Tags: xml, xsd

Tengo un archivo XML al cual tengo que hacer un Schema, y no tengo NI IDEA de cómo hacerlo. A raíz de utilizar varios validadores y conseguido crear algo que parece que es válido, pero necesito insertar un `keyref` que no consigo implementar:

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE CLIENTES[
<!ELEMENT CLIENTES (CLIENTE+)>
<!ELEMENT CLIENTE (NOMBRE, NIF, DIR_SOC, TEL, CONTACTO+)>
<!ELEMENT NOMBRE (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT NIF (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT DIR_SOC (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT TEL (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT CONTACTO (NOMBRE_CON, MAIL_CON, TEL_CON)>
<!ELEMENT NOMBRE_CON (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT MAIL_CON (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT TEL_CON (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST CLIENTE COD ID #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST CLIENTE FACT_MED  NMTOKEN  #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST CLIENTE CATEGORIA (HABITUAL|ESPORADICO|RECURRENTE) #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST CLIENTE SOCIOS IDREFS #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST  CLIENTE  BOLSA (SI|NO) #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST CLIENTE NUM_TRAB NMTOKEN #IMPLIED>
]>
<CLIENTES>
  <CLIENTE 
  COD="CODIGOUNO"
  FACT_MED="CODIGOFAC"
  CATEGORIA="HABITUAL"
  SOCIOS = "CODIGODOS"
  BOLSA="SI"
  NUM_TRAB="0001"
  >
    <NOMBRE>AARON</NOMBRE>
    <NIF>72198164Z</NIF>
    <DIR_SOC>GILERA 10</DIR_SOC>
    <TEL>635770481</TEL>
    <CONTACTO>
      <NOMBRE_CON>FRAN</NOMBRE_CON>
      <MAIL_CON>KORBATOS@GMAIL.COM</MAIL_CON>
      <TEL_CON>942820653</TEL_CON>
    </CONTACTO>
  </CLIENTE>
  
  <CLIENTE 
  COD="CODIGODOS"
  FACT_MED="CODIGOFACDOS"
  CATEGORIA="HABITUAL"
  SOCIOS = "CODIGOUNO"
  BOLSA="NO"
  NUM_TRAB="0002"
  >
    <NOMBRE>MERCEDES</NOMBRE>
    <NIF>72196513T</NIF>
    <DIR_SOC>SAN CRISTOBAL 10</DIR_SOC>
    <TEL>635770481</TEL>
    <CONTACTO>
      <NOMBRE_CON>MARI</NOMBRE_CON>
      <MAIL_CON>MERIGU00@GMAIL.COM</MAIL_CON>
      <TEL_CON>942820653</TEL_CON>
    </CONTACTO>
  </CLIENTE>
</CLIENTES>
```

Y de momento tengo esto del del Schema:

XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="CLIENTES">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="CLIENTE">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="NOMBRE" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="NIF" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="DIR_SOC" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="TEL" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
              <xs:element name="CONTACTO">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="NOMBRE_CON" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="MAIL_CON" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="TEL_CON" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="COD" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="FACT_MED" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="CATEGORIA" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="SOCIOS" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="BOLSA" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="NUM_TRAB" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:keyref name="keyClient" refer="keyClient">
            <xs:selector xpath="CLIENTE">
            <xs:field xpath="CLIENTE">
        </xs:keyref>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Pero repito, en cualquier validador me pone que ese `keyref` es erróneo por todas partes. En la documentación que leo no consigo interpretar nada claro (quizá porque ya estoy obcecado).

¿Cómo podría hacer correctamente ese XSD?
Gracias de antebrazo.

Comment: cuales son las instrucciones de tu profesor???

Comment: Literalmente:
"Transformad ese XML con ese DTD en un XSD. Apáñatelas, tienes la documentación subida a la plataforma". Veo la documentación, agrego el keyref tal cual lo indica, y me saltan 3 errores. Así que ya pido ayuda por aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Los elementos dentro del keyref no estaban cerrados...

```
 <xs:keyref name="keyClient" refer="keyClient">
            <xs:selector xpath="CLIENTE"/>
            <xs:field xpath="CLIENTE"/>
        </xs:keyref>
```

Se cierran y solucionadísimo...

Comment: entonces tu pregunta esta mal planteada; la pregunta no es como se hace; era que estaba mal ... y lo que has demostrado es un error tipográfico o de sintaxis...

Comment: Claro, estaba mal, pero realmente si estaba preguntando como se hacía lo del keyref, ya que no sabía identificar el error. Ahora que sem no hay problema.